# How to copy an 800GB mongoDB in a few hours?

Tags: linux, mongodb

I will visit a client's industry location for a few hours and have to copy the data from his mongoDB server. The data is currently above 800gb in size. I tried to replicate the data remotely but it is very slow, and hence I will visit the physical location to clone the data. Few options I found are LVM, mongodump, mongoexport, and until now LVM seems the best option. Is there a js query that can solve this situation or what might be the best course of action for this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the operating system? It seems to be Linux.

Comment: Yes it is Linux.

Comment: What distribution? and which version?

Comment: I am not sure. I will only get to know when I am there. Is there a generic solution where the distribution and version does not matter?

Comment: You need to know if the data is on LVM. Also you need to know if you need to copy the data online, or you can take the volume offline.

Comment: Please add to your question an output of `lsblk` from the source system and from the destination system.

Answer (score 1):

Make a mirror partition or disk as a LVM PV (physical volume) and make sure both are in sync. Then just take out one of the disks with you.

Before doing any changes in production, experiment with 2 VMs. One that is the "local VM" and another that is "client VM". Have a disk volume that you detach from the first VM with the mirror, then attach it to the 2nd VM. Document all steps and all troubleshooting steps.

By LVM I mean [Linux device mapper based Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))

If the mongodb data is not on LVM, or speed is most important limiting factor and you can take the disks offline, you can:

- stop all services using any partition/volume from the volume you want to mirror
- unmount all partitions from the disk you need to copy or at least the mongodb one
- copy using `dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY`, where sdX is the source disk and sdY is the destination disk. Make sure you understand the `dd` command and what a block device is before using it blindly.

Comment: I have an external hard drive that I will take with me to the location. And I will have a few hours in my hand. Will this time be enough to make the mirror partition LVM ?

Comment: You need USB3.0 but, if possible, take the disk out of enclosure and attach it to a SATA interface. It should take be enough 2h, but depends on a lot of factors. Also check `--minrecoveryrate` option.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lv

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes we can take the disks offline during that time as it will be closed hours. I think unmounting and copying the data would be the best option.

Comment: If the disk is almost full, or you have a lot of files (100k or more), `dd` is faster. Otherwise just copy files from one disk to another. But make sure you are using USB3 at least, or take out the disk and use SATA cable.